# Concuming Web services from Apple PAstry Kit

Tags: iphone, web-services, pastrykit

I'm about to implement a web app with pastry kit but I'd like to have it fetching data from a backend hosted on the net.

This backend is reacheable via a Web service... IS there a method in PAstry kit allowing me to call directly a web service and parse response data to update my page ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you aware that PasrtyKit is an Apple project that has not been made publicly available and seems to have only been used by Apple in one project and that all the information and code libraries available have been reversed engineered by people curious as to what is in the package and therefore might change or go away at any moment and has no Apple documentation or support?

Given that the short answer to you question is you will have to google for what is available and then hack it yourself.

You might also want to look at AdLib. It's like Pastry but drives the documentation for the iPad and it might be a bit more accessible as it was built later than Pastry Kit.

Also it is just a guess on my part but i suspect the data sources as they work in DashCode and are reasonably well documented should work in AdLib or PastryKit as Apple would have no reason to change the model.